# Meteor Shopify API: Post metafield to collection by collection ID

Tags: javascript, meteor, shopify

Using [froatsnook:shopify](https://github.com/froatsnook/meteor-shopify/)

Trying to get the metafields for a collection. I have the collection ID. According to [Shopify's API Documentation](https://docs.shopify.com/api/metafield#index), I should be able to get metafields for a collection, but I'm not seeing the parameter for it.

Code:

```
getShopifyCollectionMetafields: function(collection_id) {

  // GET /admin/products/#{id}/metafields.json
  var meta = ShopifyAPI.getProductMetafields({id: collection_id});

  console.log(meta)
}
```

Which returns an empty array (which makes sense, I'm trying to pass a collection ID where it expects a product ID - but not sure what to do).

Comment: Looking at the SmartCollections object, it doesn't have a field for Metafields. So, there's no API call that can return this value for you. However, apparently this is legitimate liquid code: {{ resource.metafields.namespace.key }}, where resource can be both a product or a collection. Looks like your answer exists, but it's hidden.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can specify your own calls if they aren't implemented, like so:

```
Shopify.API.define({
   "name": "getCollectionMetafields",
   "method": "GET",
   "path": "/admin/custom_collections/#{id}/metafields.json",
   "returns": "metafield",
   "description": "Get a collection's metafields"
});
```